# MongoDB: Slow query, even with index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a webpage, which uses MongoDB for storing and retrieving various measurements. Suddenly, in some point, my webpage became so sluggish it became unusable. It turns out, my database is the culprit.

I searched for and have not found any solution for my problem, and I apologize, as I am pretty new to MongoDB and pulling my hair out at the moment.

Version of MongoDB I am using is 2.4.6, on VM Machine with 20GB RAM, which runs Ubuntu server 12.04. There is no replica or sharding set up.

Firstly, I set my profiling level to 2 and it revealed the slowest query:

```
db.system.profile.find().sort({"millis":-1}).limit(1).pretty()
{
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "station.measurement",
        "query" : {
                "$query" : {
                        "e" : {
                                "$gte" : 0
                        },
                        "id" : "180"
                },
                "$orderby" : {
                        "t" : -1
                }
        },
        "ntoreturn" : 1,
        "ntoskip" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 3295221,
        "keyUpdates" : 0,
        "numYield" : 6,
        "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(12184722),
                        "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                        "r" : NumberLong(5636351),
                        "w" : NumberLong(5)
                }
        },
        "nreturned" : 0,
        "responseLength" : 20,
        "millis" : 6549,
        "ts" : ISODate("2015-03-16T08:57:07.772Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

I ran that specific query with .explain() and looks like, it uses index as it should, but it takes too long. I also ran that same query on my another, drastically weaker server and sput out the results like a champ in a second.

```
> db.measurement.find({"id":"180", "e":{$gte:0}}).sort({"t":-1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_1_t_-1_e_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 660385,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1981098,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 3301849,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 7,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 7243,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "id" : [
                        [
                                "180",
                                "180"
                        ]
                ],
                "t" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "e" : [
                        [
                                0,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "station:27017"
}
```

Next, I looked into indexes of **measurement** collection and it looked fine to me:

```
> db.measurement.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "t" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "t_1"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "d" : 1,
                        "_id" : -1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "id_1_d_1__id_-1"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "t" : -1,
                        "e" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "id_1_t_-1_e_1"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "t" : -1,
                        "e" : -1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "id_1_t_-1_e_-1"
        }
]
```

Here is also the rest of information of my collection:

```
> db.measurement.stats()
{
        "ns" : "station.measurement",
        "count" : 157835456,
        "size" : 22377799512,
        "avgObjSize" : 141.77929395027692,
        "storageSize" : 26476834672,
        "numExtents" : 33,
        "nindexes" : 5,
        "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
        "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000028617,
        "systemFlags" : 0,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 30996614096,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 6104250656,
                "t_1" : 3971369360,
                "id_1_d_1__id_-1" : 8397896640,
                "id_1_t_-1_e_1" : 6261548720,
                "id_1_t_-1_e_-1" : 6261548720
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I tried adding new index, repairing whole database, reindex. What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate any help as I desperately ran out of ideas.

**UPDATE 1:**

I added two indexes as suggested by Neil Lunn, some of the queries are a LOT faster:

```
{
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "e" : 1,
                        "t" : -1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "id_1_e_1_t_-1",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "e" : -1,
                        "t" : -1
                },
                "ns" : "station.measurement",
                "name" : "id_1_e_-1_t_-1",
                "background" : true
        }
```

Results I've got are interesting (not sure though they are relevant)

Next two queries differs by "id" only. Please notice, each query uses different index, why? Should I delete older ones?

```
> db.measurement.find({"id":"119", "e":{$gte:0}}).sort({"t":-1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_1_t_-1_e_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 840747,
        "nscannedObjects" : 840747,
        "nscanned" : 1047044,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1056722,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1311344,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 4,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 3730,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "id" : [
                        [
                                "119",
                                "119"
                        ]
                ],
                "t" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "e" : [
                        [
                                0,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "station:27017"
}

> db.measurement.find({"id":"180", "e":{$gte:0}}).sort({"t":-1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_1_e_1_t_-1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 0,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 45,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "id" : [
                        [
                                "180",
                                "180"
                        ]
                ],
                "e" : [
                        [
                                0,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ],
                "t" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "station:27017"
}
```

Could the problem be somewhere else? What could cause that sudden "sluggishness"? I have several other collections, where queries are suddenly slower also.

Oh, and another thing. On that other server I have, indexes are the same as here before I added new ones. Yes, collection is a bit smaller but it is several times faster.

Comment: Well formed as a question. I does seem that you are scanning more "t" entries than "e". As an experiment, try changing the index and query order to place the ordered emphasis on "e" before "t". Change documents suggest this should not change the result, but your results would be interesting to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thank you! I will add new indexes (id_1_e_1_t_-1 and id_1_e_-1_t_-1) and let you know about the results anytime soon as building indexes is going to take some time.

Comment: Hey, I successfully built those indexes and tested them with some queries. I updated my question with the results :)

Comment: So the results seem to see a positive improvement. Do you understand why? Or do we need to take this further?

Comment: I don't understand why another index is chosen for a query, where only a value for "id" is different. I'm surely missing something here... Please do tell more. I really, really appreciate your help! Could it be that I somehow corrupted my database?

Comment: Do you have 840747 documents with id 180?

Answer (score 2):

Then point here was in both the index and query ordering selections.

If you look at your earlier output from `.explain()` you will see that that there is a "min/max" range on the "t" element in your expression. By "moving that to the end" of the evaluation, you allow other filtering elements that are more important to the overall expression ( determine less possible matches of "e" to be the main factor before scanning though "t" in basically "everything".

It's a little bit DBA, but in the NoSQL world I do believe this becomes a programmer problem.

You essentially need to construct your "shortest match path" along the selected keys in order to get the most effective scan. That is why the altered results executes much faster.